# Algebraic solution of high degree polynomials

Tags: polynomials, roots, radicals

In layman terms, why is it [not possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem) to algebraically solve polynomials of degree five and higher?

Comment: I suspect there is no good answer in "layman terms", Mathematicians (Abel and Galois) had to invent some deep new theories to prove it. You need about a semester of college level abstract algebra to see a proof. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116814/what-does-insolvability-of-the-quintic-mean-exactly

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxNq-hQwvn0 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pdYe4BKcm74

Answer (score 0):

One author phrased it thusly (more or less): In a polynomial, every root is *an irrational* function of the coefficients, but every coefficient is *only a rational* function of the roots.  This dichotomy sets up a sort of 'internal tension' between the roots and the coefficients, which increases with the degree of the polynomial.  By degree 5 the 'tension' has exceeded the representational capacity of nested root-extractions.